# React native ios RNFirebase dependency Analysis Error. Unable to run command 'Libtool libRNFirebase.a' - this target might include its own product

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I am new in React native development, however I am getting the blow error

```
Unable to run command 'Libtool libRNFirebase.a' - this target might include its own product.
```

Here is my podfile

```
target 'TheClub' do
 .....

  pod 'Firebase'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'


  pod 'react-native-fcm', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-fcm'

  target 'TheClubTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end

end

target 'TheClub-tvOS' do

  target 'TheClub-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths

  end

end
```

I have included my RNFirebase.xcodeproj file inside Libraries folder

Also I have make sured, a file libRNFirebase.a is in "Linked binary with libraries"

Please please, help me to come out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution,

need to replace

```
pod 'Firebase'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
```

To

```
pod 'Firebase', '~> 5.9.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 5.9.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth', '~> 5.9.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '~> 5.9.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Database', '~> 5.9.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore', '~> 5.9.0'
```

Thanks "Nguyen Duc Hoang", really a good video.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iEpmEAlUhmc

Happy coding